# Is there anyway to perform partial retrieves (paging) for data coming from Azure Table Storage via GetSharedAccessSignature?

Tags: javascript, azure-table-storage

I have browser-based dashboards that currently request a ton of data directly from Azure Table Storage via SharedTokens.  Tokens they get from GetSharedAccessSignature calls made to our Web API servers, beforehand.

The calls for tokens and subsequently for storage data are made /every minute/ to grab the latest data that has been added to table storage

I'd like to minimize the amount of calls to our API servers and provide tokens that are "good enough" for a long time, not just a few minutes.  This can be easily done by expanding the PK and RK ranges.

**However**, if the calls with PK and RK ranges currently return 1 minute of data, in the future they will start returning a ton of data, as dashboards are kept open for a long time.

**Thus the question:** Is there any way for the browser to only retrieve a few rows of data from a shared-access query made to table storage?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify `$top` in your request Url to limit the maximum results returned per page.

Find more details regarding the REST API here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-entities